# How to pass values to Anchor error messages

Tags: anchor, error

Is there a way to pass values to Anchor error messages that can be read by Anchor clients? Ex. How would I pass the value of `data.data` below? If this is not possible, what is the best way to retrieve this value if running on devnet?

```
#[program]
mod hello_anchor {
    use super::*;
    pub fn set_data(ctx: Context<SetData>, data: MyAccount) -> Result<()> {
        if data.data >= 100 {
            return err!(MyError::DataTooLarge);
        }
        ctx.accounts.my_account.set_inner(data);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[error_code]
pub enum MyError {
    #[msg("MyAccount may only hold data below 100")]
    DataTooLarge
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `msg` macro inside the `if` condition:

```
pub fn set_data(ctx: Context<SetData>, data: MyAccount) -> Result<()> {
    if data.data >= 100 {
        msg!("{}",data.data);
        return err!(MyError::DataTooLarge);
    }
    ctx.accounts.my_account.set_inner(data);
    Ok(())
}
```

Now `data.data` will appear in the program log if the size is above 100. However, it won't be shown separately in the error message.

You will need to implement `Debug` trait if `data.data` is a custom type.